# Find Table Row Index for Dynamically Generated Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

**Here is my scenario:**

I have a table that displays the Name, Age, and Details content on each row. When a user selects the `Details` button, it should trigger a modal and show additional content specific to that Person in the table.

**Issue at hand:**

I am using `Razor syntax` and dynamically generating the rows within the table.

> **Question:** How can I get the row index value for that specific row when selecting the `Details` button

**Additional Notes:**

I did some research online, but couldn't find anything that helped me in my scenario.

**Html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var viewModel in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@viewModel.Name</td>
                <td>@viewModel.Age</td>
                <td><button onclick="PersonViewModel(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-modal"><span class="fa fa-external-link-square"></span> Details</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function PersonViewModel(x) {
    $('body').on('click', 'a.showMore', function(event) {
        var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        alert("Row index is: " + rowIndex);
    });
}
```

Comment: How `index` will be helpful? and Where is `a.showMore` element?

Comment: what is your problem with the code now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding event in the `PersonViewModel` click handler. In order to get the index of parent `tr`, you need to use the `x` object.

*Use*

```
function PersonViewModel(x) {
    var rowIndex = $(x).closest('tr').index();
    alert("Row index is: " + rowIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. I think this will help you.

`$(this).parents('tr')).index()`

This will give you parent tr and index() function will give index of that tr.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code instead of your

```
function PersonViewModel(x) {
     var index = $(".table tr").index( $(x).parents('tr'));
     alert(index);
}
```